# OOPS reusability of Code for reporting

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Currently I have a requirement for generating a few reports by querying SQL database and displaying it on a web page. I can probably go for SSRS as that would be helpful for reporting. But was just thinking if this can be written as components anyway so that, in future for any new reports that needs to be generated, I can re-use any of the existing C# library that I would write now.

In short, wanted to know as to how I can abstract out the design for report generation so that I need not write same piece of code again and again.. For example, Probably I can pass in the connection string and the Stored Procedure name that needs to be executed and I get back the result. I am not currently thinking about generalizing the UI display part but just the Business logic or Data retrieval process so that I need not repeat the same code always.

Thanks,
Vignesh

Comment: Usually reports are different. They require different input data, different procedures (if you use them) and produce different output. In order to do some generalization, you need something common in your reports. Executing stored procedure by name can be generalized in your DAL, but its not relevant to reporting.

Comment: Thanks for getting back quickly. Yes, I do understand that for generating reports, the Input parameters, Stored Procedure & Output is going to vary between reports. But just wanted to know if we can somehow pull out some components that we can reuse between the reports. Might be just a very small components... So there is no way that we can generalize it which will help us in reusing any component?

I know its a very vague question to ask... But was just thinking if I can somehow design in a way that it would help me in thinking in terms of components.